# JSQMessageViewController : Static InputBar hides itself behind keyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

The static Input-Bar hides itself as I click on the textview..
I've been searching over for more than 3 hours couldn't find anything..
I came across various issues on github but couldn't find a replica of mine.
Any help would be appreciated..
Also I've added super.methodCall in all viewController's lifecycle method, and did other things .. nothing seems to be working.

[image: Image attached]

Now this is what happens when I swipe up :
out of nowhere that black bottom bar appears..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This library is deprecated. Please read [blog](http://www.jessesquires.com/blog/officially-deprecating-jsqmessagesviewcontroller/) post for details.